# How to fix the trouble relating to max_input_vars in php.ini

Tags: php, xampp

while working with php and sql I got the following warning

> Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1500. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0

Accordingly I have modified the file php.ini-production, php.ini-development and php.ini in c/xampp/php and set `max_input_vars` from 1500 to 15000. 
But it still gives the warning. How to fix it.

Comment: `phpinfo();` and double check what ini file is being loaded? Also, make sure you restart apache/nginx/whatever.

Comment: Are you sure that the value you have changed is not commented?

Comment: You could try setting it in the php file to check it works like that : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php